# AssertionError at /login/ sensitive_post_parameters didn't receive an HttpRequest, On login

Tags: python, django, authentication, django-custom-user

I use Django Custom User Model. Everything works fine in Admin - login, logout etc. However when i try to call login from my own view.py:

```
def my_login(request, *args, **kwargs):
    response = login(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return response
```

I get the following error:

```
AssertionError at /cust/login/
sensitive_post_parameters didn't receive an HttpRequest. If you are decorating a classmethod, be sure to use @method_decorator.

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://localhost:8000/cust/login/
Django Version: 1.6.1
Python Version: 2.7.3

Traceback:
File "virtual_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response 114. response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "virtual_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view 69. return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "virtual_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view 57.    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
File "virtual_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch 399.response = self.handle_exception(exc)
File "virtual_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch 396.response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "virtual_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/decorators.py" in handler 49.return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "virtual_env/myproject/myidentity/views.py" in my_login 13.response = login(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "virtual_env/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/debug.py"in sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper 68."sensitive_post_parameters didn't receive an HttpRequest. If you "

Exception Type: AssertionError at /cust/login/
Exception Value: sensitive_post_parameters didn't receive an HttpRequest. If you are decorating a classmethod, be sure to use @method_decorator.
Request information:
GET: No GET data
```

Didn't find much reference about this issue, except this:
[Django AssertionError "sensitive_post_parameters didn't receive an HttpRequest" on add users in admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19139668/django-assertionerror-sensitive-post-parameters-didnt-receive-an-httprequest)

Thank you

Comment: Could it be that you are not sending in the csrf token and this makes the csrf decorator for the django login view return None instead of a request to be further passed down to the `sensitive_post_parameters` decorator?

Comment: i do send it. another experiment was disabling csrf by using @csrf_exempt, and yet no change, still getting the same error at login

Answer (score 0):

**WORKAROUND**. I'm not a django expert, and very likely this is not the most healthy solution, however digging into the course of the **login** process i came across this **Assertion** command in the Django site-packages, that was blocking the code just beneath it which looks quite reasonable, after commenting the assertion, it works just fine.

```
virtual_env > lib > python2.7 > site-packages > django > views > decorators > debug.py

def decorator(view):
        @functools.wraps(view)
        def sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper(request, *args, **kwargs):
            '''
            assert isinstance(request, HttpRequest), (
              "sensitive_post_parameters didn't receive an HttpRequest. If you "
              "are decorating a classmethod, be sure to use @method_decorator."
            )
            '''
            if parameters:
                request.sensitive_post_parameters = parameters
            else:
                request.sensitive_post_parameters = '__ALL__'
            return view(request, *args, **kwargs)
        return sensitive_post_parameters_wrapper
    return decorator
```

Comment: def not the way to go :) you should try making this question more visible to the Django folks. Or you can put together a quick gist to reproduce it and maybe someone would take a stab at it with the debugger.